# Convergence error in simulation

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, simulation

I have a doubt. What does it mean to get a convergence error in simulation?

What does it actually mean and how can it be eliminated?

Comment: Please add more details such as the software that you are using and the system that you are trying to simulate. Usually `convergence error` means that some iterative algorithm is **not** getting closer and closer (converging) to the solution as iterations progress. Eliminating it depends on the software and problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you for the comment

Comment: It's quite common to see convergence errors arise when a sim is trying to calculate the DC operating point of a circuit.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to convey in simple terms.

Comment: @Newbie Convergence is a simple mathematical/numerical idea. For iterative solutions (such as versions of the Newton/Raphson method), successive steps can converge or diverge. If diverging, the process runs out towards infinity -- not useful. If it converges, then it moves closer and closer towards a value. It is easy to test if successive steps are getting closer or further away. If a Spice program reports a convergence error then it has either detected a divergence or else it has detected oscillation between values that aren't converging. No panacea answer exists -- each situation is unique.

Comment: @jonk, Thank you for your answer